# Is there a way to force a NSURLSessionDownloadTask start when battery is low?

Tags: swift, ios13, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I’m working on a File provider extension and I’m facing a problem. As soon as I try to start a NSURLSessionDownloadTask calling the method resume(), it doesn’t start if the device has a battery level below 20% but I see that other file providers as iCloud, Dropbox, Google Drive are still working. the download start also if I trigger resume() from my main app. Do you know some way to get the task starting or some other alternative to download a file in low battery mode?

I have already tried to run everything on main thread but unsuccessfully.